# Implement ConvND in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, convolution

So I need a ND convolutional layer that also supports complex numbers. So I decided to code it myself.

I tested this code on numpy alone and it worked. Tested with several channels, 2D and 1D and complex. However, I have problems when I do it on TF.

This is my code so far:

```
def call(self, inputs):
    with tf.name_scope("ComplexConvolution_" + str(self.layer_number)) as scope:
        inputs = self._verify_inputs(inputs)            # Check inputs are of expected shape and format
        inputs = self.apply_padding(inputs)             # Add zeros if needed
        output_np = np.zeros(                           # I use np because tf does not support the assigment
            (inputs.shape[0],) +                        # Per each image
            self.output_size,                           # Image out size
            dtype=self.input_dtype                      # To support complex numbers
        )
        img_index = 0
        for image in inputs:
            for filter_index in range(self.filters):
                for i in range(int(np.prod(self.output_size[:-1]))):  # for each element in the output
                    index = np.unravel_index(i, self.output_size[:-1])
                    start_index = tuple([a * b for a, b in zip(index, self.stride_shape)])
                    end_index = tuple([a+b for a, b in zip(start_index, self.kernel_shape)])
                    # set_trace()
                    sector_slice = tuple(
                        [slice(start_index[ind], end_index[ind]) for ind in range(len(start_index))]
                    )
                    sector = image[sector_slice]
                    new_value = tf.reduce_sum(sector * self.kernels[filter_index]) + self.bias[filter_index]
                    # I use Tied Bias https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/37748/75968
                    output_np[img_index][index][filter_index] = new_value  # The complicated line
                    img_index += 1
        output = apply_activation(self.activation, output_np)
    return output
```

`input_size` is a tuple of shape (dim1, dim2, ..., dim3, channels). An 2D rgb conv for example will be (32, 32, 3) and `inputs` will have shape (None, 32, 32, 3).

The output size is calculated from an equation I found in this paper: [A guide to convolution arithmetic for deep learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.07285)

```
out_list = []
for i in range(len(self.input_size) - 1):   # -1 because the number of input channels is irrelevant
    out_list.append(int(np.floor((self.input_size[i] + 2 * self.padding_shape[i] - self.kernel_shape[i]) / self.stride_shape[i]) + 1))
out_list.append(self.filters)
```

Basically, I use `np.zeros` because if I use `tf.zeros` I cannot assign the `new_value` and I get:
`TypeError: 'Tensor' object does not support item assignment`

However, in this current state I am getting:
`NotImplementedError: Cannot convert a symbolic Tensor (placeholder_1:0) to a numpy array.`

On that same assignment. I don't see an easy fix, I think I should change the strategy of the code completely.

Comment: I even have to do that ugly `index = 0` and `index += 1` instead of `enumerate` because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62467248/5931672). With TF 2 they are at least on the right track but they have yet some work to do before they do it more "pythonic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I did it in a very inefficient way based in this [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/14132#issuecomment-483002522), also commented [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-replace-values-by-index-in-a-tensor-with-tensorflow-2-0-510994fe6c5f) but at least it works:

```
new_value = tf.reduce_sum(sector * self.kernels[filter_index]) + self.bias[filter_index]
indices = (img_index,) + index + (filter_index,)
mask = tf.Variable(tf.fill(output_np.shape, 1))
mask = mask[indices].assign(0)
mask = tf.cast(mask, dtype=self.input_dtype)
output_np = array * mask + (1 - mask) * new_value
```

I say inefficient because I create a whole new array for each assignment. My code is taking ages to compute for the moment so I will keep looking for improvements and post here if I get something better.